# Can i view my files in the emulator

Tags: android

I have just started to develop for android.
My question is can I view (display) the files of emulator in the emulator but not in DDMS.
and thank you for your answer.

I mean

for exemple,this is my situation:
I will develop an application android to decode an image and save the pixels of image in the file,so can i view this file.
thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by files of the emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean from program installed on your computer of from emulator directly? If you want to view files from emulator directly you can always install a file manager for example - [ES](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) - on your emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy files via ADB from device and view as well on your system.

Docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#copyfiles

Comment: but if i copy an image for exemple in emulator,can i find it;this my question